# Seaborn Clustermap, kernel dies during calculation

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a Data Frame lokking like this:

```
              value_1   value_2
test_id                        
A1BG        -0.956960      -inf
A1BG-AS1    -1.186835 -1.689504
A1CF        -2.941882      -inf
A2M          0.966581  1.031764
A2M-AS1     -1.188544 -1.231258
A2ML1            -inf -1.787149
A2MP1            -inf      -inf
A3GALT2     -0.885212 -0.587419
A4GALT       0.981555  0.876730
A4GNT            -inf      -inf
AA06             -inf      -inf
AAAS         1.364746  1.410399
AACS         1.044108  0.983331
AACSP1      -1.421534 -1.514185
```

It has around 25000 rows. Now i want to plot it as a heatmap with clustering. I used the following command:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Data=pd.read_table("C://Users/Kevin/Desktop/Test.txt", sep="\t", header=0, index_col=0)
Data['value_1']=np.log10(Data['value_1'])
Data['value_2']=np.log10(Data['value_2'])
print(Data)
Data.fillna(0)

sb.clustermap(Data)
```

But the only thing that happens is:

```
Kernel died, restarting
```

What Am i missing?

Comment: Is the data frame that you show in the first part of your question the output of ``print(Data)``, or does that part show the content of your file ``Test.txt``?

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/449

Comment: This is the output of the print() command

Comment: @mwaskom I still don´t see the reason why the Data.fillna(0) command does not work

Comment: Because that method returns a new dataframe, it does not change the values in place (unless you use `inplace=True`).

Comment: Also `fillna` fills nans but you have inf.

Comment: And, incidentally, you probably don't want to handle log(0) by replacing the value with 0 (i.e. log(1))

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this was the case. Your´re right, i don´t want to replace it with 0. `Data=Data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` an then dropna() would be a possibilty?

Comment: A common thing to do in this situation is `log(data + eps)` where eps is some small value that makes everything positive but doesn't otherwise disturb relative magnitude of the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the comments, the solution is to assign `Data.fillna(0)` to a new variable, or to use it with `inplace=True`. In this particular case, it would also be more suitable to replace `np.inf` or to add a small number before taking the log of the elements (`log(data + small_number)`).